# droid Login Stub Not Working Correctly

Tags: android

I built a local stub to test that my login system is working. However, it's not working and I can't logon and I can't figure out why. Probably being stupid and missing something obvious but here's the code:

In my LOGIN ACTIVITY:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
commuhelper ch = new commuhelper();      
switch (ch.PerformLogin(username, password))
{
case -1:
lblResult.setText("Could not communicate with Server.");
break;
case 0: 
lblResult.setText("Login failed. Check your credentials.");
break;
case 1:
lblResult.setText("Login successful");
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Main.class);
startActivity(loginIntent);
finish();
break;
default:
lblResult.setText("unexpected response.");
break;
}          
}
});
```

In my COMMUHELPER

```
package com.MyApp;
public class commuhelper {
private int LOCAL_DEBUG = 1;
public int PerformLogin(String username, String password)
{
int ret_val = -2;
if(LOCAL_DEBUG == 1)
{
if(username.equals("guest") && password.equals("guest"))
ret_val = 1;
else
ret_val = 0;
}
else
{
ret_val = -3;
}
return ret_val;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? What does the 'PerformLogin' method return when you test it?